# How to keep object passed by rvalue reference alive without copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, rvalue-reference

I am trying to pass `Child` as r-value to `Parent` and save it there **without copying the `Child`**.

```
Parent p{ Child{} };

cout << "----Done----" << endl;
```

And now the implementation:

```
class Child
{
public:
    Child() { cout << "Child: created" << endl; }

    ~Child() { cout << "Child: destroyed" << endl; }
};

class Parent
{
    // store as r-value ref
    Child&& child;

public:
    // pass by r-value ref and move
    Parent(Child&& c) :child(move(c))
    {
        cout << "Parent: created" << endl;
    }

    ~Parent() { cout << "Parent: destroyed" << endl; }
};
```

The output is:

> Child: created
>   Parent: created
>   **Child: destroyed**
>   ------Done------
>   Parent: destroyed

[cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references) says: `Rvalue references can be used to extend the lifetimes of temporary objects`

Question 1: Why isn't `Child` destroyed in the very end (or at least after *Done*)?
Question 2: How to make it live longer?

P.S:

```
Child& child;
...
Parent(Child c) :child(c)
```

Gives the exact same result.

Comment: "*without any copies*" What *exactly* do you mean by this? What's wrong with just giving `Parent` a `Child` value that you move-construct into? A reference references an object; it doesn't *own* it. Why do you want to use a reference to manage ownership like this?

Comment: I meant *without copying the Child object*. Cppreference says that rvalue ref can be used to extend object's lifetime. Imagine Child object is a string. How can I initialize Parent with it and keep it for later without beeing copied another time *and* beeing destroyed?

Comment: Could you give a link to the cppref page you are quoting? I'm pretty sure it does not say exactly what you read, but it would take me some time to find that page again.

Comment: Its here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference under "Rvalue references"

Comment: Your question is very much an XY problem. It makes little sense to keep an r-value inside an object and is dangerous too. Maybe you want to look into unique_ptr or shared_ptr instead.

Comment: The life extension for rvalue reference does not apply to class members, but local variable only. You can just declare `Child child;` and do `Parent(Child&& c) :child(c)` It calls the move constructor of Child and will not cause duplicate/copying

Comment: Your output and question suggests you are confusing "copying" with "construction". An object can be constructed in the context of move-semantics (via a move-constructor) and still not be "copied".  That is the very point of move-semantics. Something that is otherwise expensive to copy (computationally or resource-wise) can rather be *moved*, and thus avoid that overhead. The "guts" have ownership transferred from one object to another, leaving the source a mere shell of its former self.

Comment: @Pari Comments are subject to disappear. All relevant information should be in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for great answer @WhozCraig, understanding of *moving* was the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references) says: `Rvalue references can be used to extend the lifetimes of temporary objects`

You are leaving out an important part of that quote. A more accurate quote is: *"Rvalue references can be used to [extend the lifetimes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) of temporary objects"*.

Notice the difference? (Don't worry too much if you don't, as it is subtle.) There is a link to an explanation of how and when the lifetime of a temporary can be extended. You've tagged this question C++11, so the bullet point that is valid until C++14 applies:

> - a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object exists. (note: such initialization is ill-formed as of DR 1696).

You bound a temporary to a reference member in a constructor initializer list. The temporary's lifespan is not extended beyond the end of the constructor. The temporary is destroyed before your object's destructor is called.

---

How to make it live longer? That gets tricky, but if the parameter is always a temporary, you could make your member a non-reference and `move` the parameter to the member. If you want more flexibility, you may need to accept some copying.

Answer (score 0):

Part of standard you've quoted refers to something like this:

```
struct A { };
int main() {
  const A &a = A{};
  ...
}
```

and now `a` will be destroyed once scope of function `main` ends. This doesn't work for class members. Passing value to function by reference (after all constructor is just a function) doesn't extent reference's lifetime. Nor does assigning it to a member variable.